# Error when importing modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I'm getting the following error when importing modules in python. I'm using jupyter notebook (python 2). I've searched through the internet but still can't quite figure out why. Any help would be so much appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import pandas as pd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e4e9959b303a> in <module>()
----> 1 import numpy as np
  2 from pandas import Series,DataFrame
  3 import pandas as pd

 /Users/...filepath.../Python/data_analysis/numpy.pyc in <module>()
      17 
      18 import numpy as np
 ---> 19 from numpy.random import randn
      20 
      21 

      ImportError: No module named random
```

I've tried adding `import random` to the above code (before the other modules) and it still gives the same error. Could this be due to the version of gfortran on my system? I have version 4.9.2

Comment: You `import numpy as np`, so then you have to do `from np.random `

Comment: Really? I don't quite understand that. The error seems to be coming from `import numpy as np` and `import pandas`. The above works completely fine in spyder-just throws errors in jupyter notebook.

Comment: You have a module called `numpy.py`, and it's finding that when you import numpy, instead of the real numpy package. Rename that to something else, and then try again.

Comment: @Thomas K, thanks so much. Indeed that was the problem. I've deleted both .pyc files (pandas.pyc, numpy.pyc) in my working directory and it now works! Thanks so much-I've spent literally the whole day trying to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont have complete code, just tried using import statements.

If we  use  `np` as per @John
`import numpy as np`
`from np.random import randn`

I am getting
`from np.random import randn`
`ImportError: No module named np.random`

I am not getting any error if I import `randn` from `numpy.random`

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
print "randn1= ", randn()

from numpy.random import rand
print "rand1= ", rand()
```

Its working for me with output as below,

```
randn1=  0.147667079884  
rand1=  0.243935746205
```

You can also try  to use `np.random.randn()`  and `np.random.rand()`  directly.

```
import numpy as np
print "randn2= ", np.random.randn()
print "rand2= ", np.random.rand()
```

I get :
`randn2=  -0.22571513741`
`rand2=  0.486507681046`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added the modules I was trying to import to the top of the code-sry I forgot this. Hope this clarifies the problem. As you can see, I didn't even try to call random at all. The error is from just trying to import pandas and numpy.

Comment: Please see Thomas K's comment above-this resolved the problem.